# Why are pictures of the Prophet Mohammed not allowed

Tags: prophet-muhammad

This confused me because surely someone must have drawn him when he was alive so why can’t there be pictures of him.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE.Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). Is your question about any historical evidence of a portrait of the Prophet, or about the permissibility of such an act?

Answer (score 2):

because in Islamic thought depiction of holy prophets including the prophet Muhammad usually ends in confusion of idolatry and worshiping, therefore they were regarded as haram to prevent such thing, it also leads to false depiction and misleading ideas about them, in general depicting people back then was viewed as a sign of disrespect
you should also keep in mind this was recent and was not quite popular back then, the depiction of holy figures these days usually leads to mockery and insults, that is why it was regarded as haram under the Islamic ruling "no harm shall be allowed and no cause of harm shall be allowed too"

Comment: Welcome to Islam! Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Please provide your textual sources for "depiction of holy prophets ... ends in confusion of idolatry and worshiping".